# Grabbing part of link on external website through PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to  grab some values I need.
What I'm trying to do now, is to grab a part of an URL.

This is how the source looks:

```
<a class="base-header-soldier-link" href="/bf3/soldier/someprofile/stats/123456789/">
  someprofile
</a>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value "123456789", without the rest of the URL.

I'm using this code to retrieve the URL:

```
foreach($html->find('.base-header-soldier-name a') as $e)
{
    $battlelog_id = $e->href;
}
```

So basically I want to strip it for the rest of the URL.

The URL can change depending on username, so "someprofile" will be replaced.

Can any of you help me out?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: explode() using / is a start, or look at preg_match()

Comment: While I know that I can retrieve the username quite easily, I've experienced problems when trying to strip the rest of the URL. I simply don't have the knowledge. I've tried to use "preg_replace" and ", but I can't manage to get it to work. I'm testing out preg_match now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a couple of ways the easiest is [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
<?php 
$url = '/bf3/soldier/someprofile/stats/123456789/';
echo basename($url);//123456789
?>
```

Or a more robust way is [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
<?php 
$url = '/bf3/soldier/someprofile/stats/123456789/';
$url_parts = pathinfo($url);
/*
Array
(
    [dirname] => /bf3/soldier/someprofile/stats
    [basename] => 123456789
    [filename] => 123456789
)
*/

echo $url_parts['filename']; //123456789
?>
```

Or even [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
<?php 
$url = '/bf3/soldier/someprofile/stats/123456789/';
$url_parts = explode('/', rtrim($url,'/'));

echo end($url_parts);//123456789
?>
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I didn't know about basename, but thanks!